# user defined string literal, is string null terminated?

Tags: c++, user-defined-literals

For user defined string literals, is the given string guaranteed null terminated if I use the following form of definition? I know that the size given with second parameter count without any termination if there is any.

```
void operator"" _x( const char* n, size_t s)
{
    std::cout << "String: " << s << " Len: " << s << std::endl;
}
```

If I use this version of definition I see no null termination character!

```
template <class T, T... Chrs>
void operator""_s() 
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Note: Your second overload is ill-formed I think, because the Standard only mandates that the template ["shall have an empty parameter-declaration-clause and its template-parameter-list shall have a single template-parameter that is a non-type template parameter pack with element type char."](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#over.literal-5)

Comment: @Rakete1111: Is it ill formed to write: `template <char...> void operator "" _d(){} "Hallo"_d;`? This did not compile with g++. Did that mean it is impossible to use any templated form with user defined string literals?

Comment: No, `template<char...> type operator""_d()` is the only allowed form. Every other use of templates is ill-formed. I don't know why it doesn't compile under g++, because it does so for me.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Yes, compiles for non-string user defined literals. But I wrote user defined *string* literals. Are you able to compile with `"test"_d;`?

Comment: Yes sorry. I read your comment too quickly. You are right, there is no way to have user defined *string* literals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> user defined string literal, is string null terminated?
>
> ```
> void operator"" _x( const char* n, size_t s)
> ```

Yes. String literals are null terminated and `n` points to such string literal.

---

> If I use this version of definition I see no null termination character!
>
> ```
> template <class T, T... Chrs>
> void operator""_s()
> ```

The standard does not allow string literal templates. There is the document [N3599](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3599.html) which proposes its addition to the standard, and it was intended for C++14 but there was [no consensus](http://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#66) and it hasn't become part of the standard yet. GCC and Clang at least appear to have already implemented it as a language extension.

Indeed, the literal operator template does not receive the null character as one of its arguments.

> Proposal N3599:
>
> the remaining arguments are the code units in the string literal (**excluding its terminating null character**).

Comment: You should mention that the second version is non-standard. [over.literal] "The declaration of a literal operator template shall have an empty parameter-declaration-clause and its
template-parameter-list shall have a single template-parameter that is a non-type template parameter pack
 with element type char."

Comment: @AndyG Added mention.

Comment: How could a conforming version of the function be written?

Comment: @rex There is no standard conforming way to write a string literal template.

Comment: I've re-written the answer to be clearer about that.

Comment: That the templated version is ill formed is new to me. Interesting that gcc did not complain about, also if --std=c++14 and -pedantic -Wextra is set!

Comment: @Klaus I suppose that the warning wasn't originally added since the implementers anticipated that it would become standard. Since C++14 was released without it, lack of warning is a GCC bug. Clang does warn when the extension is used.